# Amount of acceptable slashes in ibase_query()

Tags: php, firebird

I'm trying to import table that contains invoice details and while it's alright when done with MySQL, `ibase_query()` seems to reject invoices with more than 2 or 3 slashes without throwing an error or exception.

To be more specific, mysqli's `prepare()` works fine with numbers like `00254/01/2015/PN/T-PL` but it won't appear in Firebird's table. However it would eventually accept `00254/01/T-PL`. I'm quite confused on how to solve that...

Comment: Post your table definition and insert statement.

Comment: Please include the code you use and errors you receive. I don't use PHP so I am not familiar with ibase, but I can't think of a reason why Firebird would choke on the number of slashes. It might point to a bug in the ibase driver.